# Roslyn: How to make codefix on context in different project?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, codefixprovider

I am trying to write a proprietary analyzer and codefix for the following problem. Bare in mind this is my first time using Roslyn APIs. I'll gladly accept any general tips and advice.

There is a huge code base with thousands of classes and a requirement for a change in the class inheritance hierarchy. I need to change the top base class of certain inheritance chains from `System.Object` to `System.MarshalByRefObject`.
The problem is that the reasoning of whether the change is needed down in one of the subclasses. The `AnalyzeSymbol` method, is passed `SymbolAnalysisContext` that points to one subclass, but the codefix is needed elsewhere.

I tried to pass the location of the baseclass declaration as `AdditionalLocations` property to the `Diagnostic` that I report. This works, sort of. I am able to retrieve this location on the `CodeFixProvider` side, but only if the location is in the same project. If the Declaration of the baseclass is in different project, as most of the time it is, the `AdditionalLocations` property is empty.

Example in code:
Derived class is flagged by the analyzer, here the dummy reason is the interface `IVisible`.

```
// Project A
class BaseClass
{
    ...
}


// Project B
class DerivedClass : BaseClass, API.IVisible
{
    ...
}
```

The expected codefix is this:

```
// Project A
class BaseClass : System.MarshalByRefObject
{
    ...
}


// Project B
class DerivedClass : BaseClass, API.IVisible
{
    ...
}
```

What is the correct way to point to a different context for the `CodeFixProvider`? Is there a better way to do this sort of refactoring?